# IMAP GetLineResponse equivalent in Indy 10?

Tags: delphi, indy

In Indy9, there was a method of the TIdImap class called GetLineResponse. This method has been removed in Indy10, so I'm wondering what I should use instead of this command in Indy10.

Here's an example of how I was using GetLineResponse in Indy9 as part of a method to download the first so many lines or bytes of an email:

```
IMAP.WriteLn('xx FETCH '+IntToStr(MsgNum)+' BODY.PEEK[TEXT]<0.'+
             IntToStr(LineCount*70)+'>');
Result := IMAP.GetLineResponse('xx',[wsOK]) = wsOK;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `TIdIMAP4.GetLineResponse()` in Indy 10. Use `TIdIMAP4.GetResponse()` instead (which also exists in Indy 9).  Or better, use `TIdIMAP4.SendCmd()` instead (which also exists in Indy 9) and let it handle the response for you.